# Allegro 5 Play Multiple Samples at Once

Tags: c++, audio, allegro5

I've come across an issue with playing samples Allegro 5. When I play a sample, I can't play that sample again until it's finished playing. Sometimes it will also not play the sample if another, different, sample is playing.

Anyway to get around this?

I play audio with a "Sound" class, which only has a play function. The rest are constuctors and member vars, all of which are used in the play function.

```
void Sound::play()
{
    al_play_sample(
        pSample,    // ALLEGRO_SAMPLE
        mGain,      // float
        mPan,       // float
        mSpeed,     // float
        getPlaymode(mPlaymode), // I use my own non-AL playmode enums. This is a private function that returns the AL version.
        NULL);      // ALLEGRO_SAMPLE_ID
}
```

The whole class:

Sound.h

```
class ContentManager;

enum Playmode
{
    BiDir,
    Loop,
    Once,
    StreamOnce,
    StreamOneDir
};

class Sound : public Trackable
{
private:
    /*  Variables
    * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    ALLEGRO_SAMPLE* pSample;

    float
        mGain,
        mPan,
        mSpeed;

    Playmode mPlaymode;

    std::string
        mAssetPath,
        mAssetName;

    /*  Private Functions
    * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE getPlaymode(Playmode playmode)
    {
        switch (playmode)
        {
            case BiDir:
                return ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE::ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_BIDIR;

            case Loop:
                return ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE::ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_LOOP;

            case Once:
                return ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE::ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE;

            case StreamOnce:
                return ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE::_ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_STREAM_ONCE;

            case StreamOneDir:
                return ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE::_ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_STREAM_ONEDIR;

            // Default to once
            default:
                return ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE::ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE;
        }
    }

public:
    /*  Constructors/Destructor
    * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    Sound();

    Sound(
        // assetPath, assetName, gain, pan, speed, playmode
        std::string assetPath, 
        std::string assetName, 
        float gain = 1.0f, 
        float pan = 0.0f, 
        float speed = 1.0f,
        Playmode playmode = Once);

    Sound(const Sound& other);

    ~Sound();

    friend class ContentManager; // My content system.

    void play();

};
```

Sound.cpp

```
#include "Sound.h"

/*  Constructors/Destructor
* * * * * * * * * * * * */
Sound::Sound()
{
    this->mAssetPath = "";
    this->mAssetName = "";
    this->mGain = 1.0f;
    this->mPan = 0.0f;
    this->mSpeed = 1.0f;
    this->mPlaymode = Once;

    this->pSample = NULL;
}

Sound::Sound(std::string assetPath, std::string assetName, float gain, float pan, float speed, Playmode playmode)
{
    this->mAssetPath = assetPath;
    this->mAssetName = assetName;
    this->mGain = gain;
    this->mPan = pan;
    this->mSpeed = speed;
    this->mPlaymode = playmode;

    this->pSample = al_load_sample((assetPath + assetName).c_str());
}

Sound::Sound(const Sound& other)
{
    this->mAssetPath = other.mAssetPath;
    this->mAssetName = other.mAssetName;    
    this->mGain = other.mGain;
    this->mPan = other.mPan;
    this->mSpeed = other.mSpeed;
    this->mPlaymode = other.mPlaymode;

    this->pSample = al_load_sample((mAssetPath + mAssetName).c_str());
}

Sound::~Sound()
{
    al_destroy_sample(pSample);
}


void Sound::play()
{
    al_play_sample(
        pSample,
        mGain,
        mPan,
        mSpeed,
        getPlaymode(mPlaymode),
        NULL);
}
```

I call the play function through the rest of my system, which would look something like this:

```
// Game->ContentManager->Sound->play()
Game::instance()->content()->getSound("somesound.wav")->play();
```

Content manager contains maps of my assets.

This is part of a larger project I'm working on for a class, but no, this part isn't homework. My professor disallowed us from having any public/top level AL codes (e.g. no public AL returns, etc).

Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Any help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it sounds like you have to reserve more samples using `al_reserve_samples(number_of_samples);`

Comment: I'll try that when I get a chance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of ppsz's answer, I did some digging and did the following based on what I found.

```
int numSamples = /*Some int*/
int reservedSamples = 0;
int i = (numSamples >= 1 ? numSamples : 1);
bool success = false;

do
{
    success = al_reserve_samples(i);

    i -= 1;
}
while (success == false || i > 0);
```

[Source](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/615634)